# yii2 imperavi widget settings in config file

Tags: yii2, redactor

How to set yii2-imperavi-widget (vova07) settings in config/web.php? In 'components' or in 'modules' array?

try in 'components':

```
'imperavi' => [
             'class' => 'vova07\imperavi\Widget',
             'settings' => [
                'lang' => 'ru',
                'removeWithoutAttr' => [],
                'minHeight' => 300,
                'pastePlainText' => true,
                'buttonSource' => true,
                'replaceDivs' => false,
                'plugins' => [
                    'clips',
                    'fullscreen',
                    'fontfamily',
                    'fontsize',
                    'fontcolor',
                    'video',
                    'table'
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

doesn't work.